# NVARCHAR in JDK 1.5

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have couple of fields in oracle which is NVARCHAR and I am using Java 1.5. If I read those values as string is that okay or is there a better approach for reading columns with NVARCHAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `ResultSet` named `rs` then this is appropriate for `NVARCHAR`:

```
String myColumn = rs.getString("my_column");
```

See [Globalization Support for JDBC Drivers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch9.htm#5669):

> Oracle JDBC drivers provide globalization support by allowing you to retrieve data from or insert data into columns of the SQL CHAR and NCHAR datatypes of an Oracle9i database. Because Java strings are encoded as UTF-16 (16-bit Unicode) for JDBC programs, the target character set on the client is always UTF-16. For data stored in the CHAR, VARCHAR2, LONG, and CLOB datatypes, JDBC transparently converts the data from the database character set to UTF-16. **For Unicode data stored in the NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, and NCLOB datatypes, JDBC transparently converts the data from the national character set to UTF-16.**

Comment: Does this mean we can't read a NVARCHAR2 without converting to UTF-16 from oracle db?

Comment: Yes it does mean that because Java itself always uses UTF-16.